# How to restore (with Time Machine) from a newer MacOS (Monterey) to an older MacOS (Catalina)?

Tags: backup, time-machine, restore

Due to office use I need to move my information from a Monterey Mac to a Catalina Mac (I can't update any further this iMac).
I've tried restoring from a previous TimeMachine but the older Mac doesn't find any backups, I've confirmed the information is backed up since 300GB out of the 1TB are used.
However I can't seem to find a way if the TimeMachine can't find any backups on my drive.

Comment: Version x of macOS (produced in year y) wasn't told about versions x+1, x+2, .... (produced in future years. y+1, y+2, ....). You can't go back easily. Try using Finder and network share to connect from Catalina Mac to Monterey Mac and copy documents, photos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Time Machine will not let you restore to an older OS.
This was true even when both the new & old OS used the same disk format. It's probably 'even more true' trying to go from Monterey back to Catalina. Catalina wants to see a Time Machine drive formatted as HFS+; Monterey uses APFS.

Catalina will still be able to read the drive, but it won't be able to think of it as a Time Machine drive.
You will have to copy data manually.

I'm unable to test this, but if it doesn't recognise it as a 'special' Time Machine drive, you will possibly be able to Get Info & 'Ignore ownership on this volume'. That will give you permissions to copy data from it like any other drive.
Work from the folder in Backups.backupdb/[MacName]/Latest
Note that database structures like Apple Mail will not be able to be used by the older OS; they will be incompatible. Regular documents should be fine.

Comment: I think there might be an error with my backup. When I ignored ownership of this volume, it didn't show any of the folders (Backups.backupdb/[MacName]/Latest).

Comment: Changing permissions shouldn't affect what you can see on the drive at all, only your ability to interact with it.